# Lazy-load content in Hugo

Tags: lazy-loading, hugo

I am thinking of building a static website using [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/). I am thinking of publishing posts onto the landing page, but I wonder if the landing page would get too big if too many posts are added to it. Therefore, I wonder if it is possible to lazy-load posts in Hugo as the user scrolls down my landing page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hugo is just a static site generator, you can implement the lazy loading feature there. Hugo will just generate the .html pages for you but doesn't care about your scripts or HTML code in the semantic way.

For basic lazy loading, it is possible to just add `loading="lazy"` attribute to your images ([see the browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=lazy%20loading)). Or you can implement some of the JavaScript libraries that are intended for this purpose.